# Creating dynamic URLs for Product Pages

Tags: urls, slug

I'm working on an ecommerce website using the HivePress theme. The issue I'm facing is that I'm looking for a way for the slugs of every product/listing page to be dynamic.

I have an attribute for every product called "stock_number", and I'd like to have it so that the URLs for every product page would be [https://domain.com/listing/{stock_number}/](https://domain.com/listing/%7Bstock_number%7D/) where the "{stock_number}" changes depending on the attribute given to the product.

At the moment it is just the post name, but ideally I'd have it be dynamic for the stock number.

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What *specific* problem are you having? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/418516/edit) to include any relevant code samples.

Comment: Not sure why you're doing this but do want to ask if you realize that this is detrimental for SEO?